# Dynamically defining functions using list elements in Python

Tags: python, function, naming

I'm trying to define a number of functions that I can then run concurrently using `multiprocessing`. In order to do this, I'm attempting to use a list of strings and iterate over the list, having each string be the name of a separate function.

Something similar to this:

```
nameList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for name in nameList:
    def name():
        #do stuff
```

In the above example, I would ideally end up with four functions, `a, b, c` and `d`.

Clearly however, this doesn't work. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Briefly: use a data structure like a list or dictionary.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  I don't find it as a duplicate of one you mentioned. This person wants to define functions with different names.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal - And you do that by adding the function references to a list or dictionary. It is a perfect duplicate. It's simply `def myfunct(): pass # do stuff` and then `name = {c:myfunc for c in 'abcd'}`, at which point the desired reference of e.g. `a` is `name['a']`. If each function is supposed to be different, they can be defined as needed in the loop, adding the reference to the defined function to the dictionary.